# Firmware flash on Linksys WRT54G v8 unsucessful, but not bricked, I don't think

Tags: flash, firmware, wrt54g

I wanted to use my Linksys router as a wireless bridge/repeater so I decided I would change the firmware to DD-WRT.  The first thing I did was downloaded vxworkskillerGv8-v3 and the DD-WRT firmware build 14929.  For tftp I used the Windows GUI app on the DD-WRT wiki.  I then configured my Windows 7 PC to turn off CTCP and changed my ip configuration to static with my ip 192.168.1.100, 255.255.255.0, and 192.168.1.1.

I then did a 30/30/30 reset on the router and once that was done I plugged my PC into port 1 with no other cables plugged in, went into the administration tab, and upgraded the firmware with the vxworkskiller.  This is where it gets strange, the wiki said it would take a few minutes before it would say that I need to restart the router, but for me the progress bar got a few ticks and after about 10 seconds it told be to reboot, so I did.  Then I used the TFTP GUI software to load the DD-WRT firmware onto it, and it didn't take any retries and took about 5 seconds.

After that I let the router sit for about 3 minutes and tried going to the web page: It didn't work.  I then tried rebooting it but still wouldn't work.  Finally I did another 30/30/30 but it STILL wouldn't go to the web page.  This whole time, my port 1 light is on and I can ping it without a problem in the command prompt.  The power light is very very dim, but doesn't look like it's flashing.  I tried upgrading the firmware again with the GUI app and it still did it on the first time without a hitch.  I will guess that the DD-WRT firmware is not getting loaded because of how quickly it gets "installed".

I think something got messed up with the vxworkskiller, but it's exhibiting the behavior of it as "the router can be pinged, but the web page cannot be browsed" so I think it's installed.  Based on what I have said thus far, what would be the next recommended action.  I was thinking trying to install the OEM firmware back on, but how do I do that, if I should?